# Splinter Cell Double Agent(PC) - Can you use the attachments that you get?

Tags: technical-issues, splinter-cell-double-agent

Ok I had played [Splinter Cell Double Agent on my PC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Clancy%27s_Splinter_Cell:_Double_Agent#Xbox_360.2C_Windows.2C_and_PlayStation_3_version), one of the odd things was that after completing all the objectives of a particular level you used to get certain rewards like the shotgun SC-20K attachment or the colored nightvision.

Can you actually use these ? Or are they just for show ? Because I could never get an option to use these.

I just want to know if that was how the game was built or is it a bug in my system ?

Comment: It's been a while since I played the game, but I don't recall getting add-ons I couldn't use.  You probably *do* need to at least get out of the prison first before you can start changing up your equipment before a mission.  Have you gotten that far and still can't equip stuff?

Comment: @Steve-O I have completed the game. Are you playing the PC version ? Then could you please specify how I can use the shotgun sc20k attachment ?